# Subtracting a normal distribution from another distribution?

Tags: r, probability, distributions, normal-distribution

I have a dataset with skewed distributions describing different samples' total variation. I know these distributions are a sum of a normal distribution (analytical variation, which I know) and a skewed distribution (biological variation, which is unknown). So I am looking for a general solution to approximate the biological variation by removing the analytical variation.

I tried a Monte Carlo approach:

The total variation is BoxCox normal

```
Total.Sample.BoxCox <- rnorm(n = 1000000, mean = 0, sd = sigma)
```

And skewed on the original scale

```
Total.Sample <- invBoxCox(Total.Sample.BoxCox, lambda = lambda)
```

The Analytical variation is a normal distribution with a known standard deviation

```
Analytical <- rnorm(n = 1000000, mean = 1, sd = 0.06)
```

I tried subtracting the analytical distribution from the total variation distribution but realized that this only increases the variance.

```
Biological <- Total.Sample - Analytical
```

Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: What are you trying to estimate from your data?

Comment: I have a dataset gathered from a large population grouping the total variation between samples from the same individuals. This distribution is skewed. Prior knowledge: this distribution is formed by an underlying normal distribution (analytical variation) and a skewed biological variation. I am figuring out how to remove the analytical variation to estimate the biological. The result would represent "a normal biological fluctuation" within an individual in the population.